# Outputting datasets in a certain order

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, filter, group-by

I want to check that, **for each `version` in `df_2`, every `scope` exists in `df_1`**. Input datasets:

```
df_1 = 

my_id        scope         feat_1         value_1    value_2     value_3          date
23784    some_code          Three              30         60          60    2022-01-01
23794    some_cod1          Seven              60         40          20    2022-01-01
23774    some_cod2          Three              90         40          60    2022-01-02
22784    some_cod3            Two              30         10          60    2022-01-03
23564    some_cod5           Five              20         40          20    2022-02-08
20784    some_cod6           Five              10         70          40    2022-02-15

df_2 =

       scope         feat_1           date     version
   some_code          Three     2022-01-01         100
   some_cod1          Seven     2022-01-01         100   
   some_cod2          Three     2022-01-02         200       
   some_cod3            Two     2022-01-03         350
   some_cod4           Four     2022-01-05         650
   some_cod5           Five     2022-02-08         700
   some_cod6           Five     2022-02-15         800
   some_cod7           Four     2022-02-15         800
```

I want a list of all the `versions` that are complete, i.e. whose scopes are all in `df_1`. I also want to transform `df_1` so that it only contains the scopes corresponding to the complete versions.

**Desired outputs:**

First `complete_versions`:

```
version     scope
100         some_code
100         some_cod1
200         some_cod2
350         some_cod3
700         some_cod5
```

Then:

```
 df_1_new =

    my_id        scope         feat_1         value_1    value_2     value_3          date
    23784    some_code          Three              30         60          60    2022-01-01
    23794    some_cod1          Seven              60         40          20    2022-01-01
    23774    some_cod2          Three              90         40          60    2022-01-02
    22784    some_cod3            Two              30         10          60    2022-01-03
    23564    some_cod5           Five              20         40          20    2022-02-08
```

**My question is: how do I output `complete_versions` first, and then derive `df_1_new` out of it?** I know one can just obtain `df_1_new` in one step, but this is not what I need.

**But how do I compute `complete_versions`?** (afterwards it is just a `join` to get `df_1_new`).

Comment: Isn't complete_versions an inner join as well? Just make sure to leave out the irrelevant columns from both tables before you join them

Answer (score 0):

To get all complete `versions` we need first to left join `df_2` and `df_1` and then filter out versions that don't have corresponding `scope` in `df_1`, i.e. filter out `versions` that have any `nulls` in `df_1` part after the join:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("version")
complete_versions = (
    df_2
    .join(df_1, df_1.scope == df_2.scope, 'left')
    .select(
        df_2.version, 
        df_1.scope, 
        (~F.max(F.isnull(df_1.my_id)).over(w)).alias("is_complete")) # assume that df_1.my_id is non-nullable
    .where("is_complete==true")
    .drop("is_complete"))
+-------+---------+
|version|    scope|
+-------+---------+
|    700|some_cod5|
|    100|some_code|
|    100|some_cod1|
|    200|some_cod2|
|    350|some_cod3|
+-------+---------+
```

And after that, we derive `df_1_new` from a simple inner join:

```
df_1_new = df_1.join(complete_versions, df_1.scope==complete_versions.scope).select(df_1['*'])
+-----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
|my_id|    scope|feat_1|value_1|value_2|value_3|      date|
+-----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
|23774|some_cod2| Three|     90|     40|     60|2022-01-02|
|23784|some_code| Three|     30|     60|     60|2022-01-01|
|23794|some_cod1| Seven|     60|     40|     20|2022-01-01|
|22784|some_cod3|   Two|     30|     10|     60|2022-01-03|
|23564|some_cod5|  Five|     20|     40|     20|2022-02-08|
+-----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
```